# how to append 'this' object into html in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day,

Im am trying to get only `tr`'s with 7 or more `td`'s on it using a loop.

```
var table = '<table>';

    $('table tr').each(function() {
        xx = $(this).children().length;
        if(xx>7)
        {
            table += this;
        }
        table+='<table>';
        console.log(xx);
     });

document.getElementById('new_table').innerHTML = table;
```

but this gives me this result

```
[object HTMLTableRowElement]
[object HTMLTableRowElement]
[object HTMLTableRowElement]
[object HTMLTableRowElement]
[object HTMLTableRowElement]
[object HTMLTableRowElement]
[object HTMLTableRowElement]
[object HTMLTableRowElement]
[object HTMLTableRowElement]
[object HTMLTableRowElement]
[object HTMLTableRowElement]
[object HTMLTableRowElement]
```

could anyone please tell me whats wrong please? Thank You verymuch..

Comment: hi @chet using this.html I am getting `undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Element.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

```
table += this.outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
table += $(this).clone().wrap('<tr></tr>').parent().html();
```

`$(this).html()` gives you only the inner html of the element. Here, in your case, you will not get TR but only all TDs inside TR.

Reference: [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

Comment: can't wrap a `<tr>` in another `<tr>` it is invalid

Comment: `this` is a `<tr>` ... and it can not have a parent `<tr>` per html specs. Your edit doesn't change that

Comment: `this` is a `<tr>`. But `$(this).html()` gives you only its children. Check it out here:  http://plnkr.co/edit/XFghfxNWKJ5PbqL4j8Hd?p=preview

Comment: you are assuming that the invalid wrap will work in all browsers

Comment: When you use `clone()` in memory copy of the element is created. It is not added to the DOM yet. So, even though I am wrapping one tr within another, when it is about to be added to the DOM, the outer tr is stripped off.

Comment: Interestingly, you can wrap it in tbody and it still works, because tbody is stripped off anyway!